# react-native-calendars - Agenda header alignment issue days not rendering properly on header

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIhMR.jpg)
If I'm selecting the first month or last month from agenda the dates are not showing propely.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKDJE.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain your issue in words. The images are confusing and dont throw much light into your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug of react-native-calendar.

It has been partially fixed with this merge:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/pull/1498

Try to update to the latest version.